# MySQL COUNT with empty column

Tags: mysql, count, distinct, string

I have a table tb1 like this:

```
id  | building  | id_connect |  
====+==========+============
1 |     1    |       "328abbc"    
2 |     3    |       "328abbc"    
3 |     4    |       "212a3b"    
4 |     1    |       "212a3b"  
5 |     2    |       ""  
6 |     2    |       ""
7 |     7    |       ""
```

I need to get the count of the distinct id_connect if the string is different to "", but each empty string ("") has to add 1...

In the example, the required result would be 5 (one "328abbc", one "212a3b" and the three ""), but I only obtain 3 with

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(id_connect))
FROM tb1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN id_connect='' THEN 1 END)
  + COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(id_connect, ''))
FROM tb1
```

Comment: See it running as an alternative on @Bohemian's sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e611a/8).

Comment: @eggyal you're a noob: `COUNT(CASE WHEN id_connect='' THEN 1 END)` is identical to `COUNT(id_connect='')`

Comment: Sorry - I meant `SUM(id_connect='')` - [see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8188f/2). It's more "leet" than the wordy case

Answer (score -1):

This works:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(if(id_connect = '', concat(id, 'text not found in id_connect'), id_connect)))
FROM tb1
```

Output:

```
5
```

See it running [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e611a/2).

Comment: @Bohemian: What if a blank's `id` matches an `id_connect`?

Comment: @eggyal then add something to it (see edited answer) - don't be pedantic